# Synchronize data between different Oracle version

Tags: oracle

Could anyone tell if it is possible to synchronize data from Oracle SE 12C to Oracle EE 12C. Im thinking to synchronize my small office data to my HQ office.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to

[Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html)

You didn't specify if you wanted a commercial or some kind of free solution.